# Why is this patent allowed? (US8240362)

Tags: patentability, us8240362

This is the most broad description of a patent that I have ever seen, and for a liquid cooling block at that. Patenting a cooling block "with an integrated pump" is the most mind boggling thing out there. How can we let someone patent an integrated pump design without saying any specifics besides that the loop with have "one dc or ac motor" and an inlet or outlet in the water reservoir. This stuff is preposterous, and the patent being granted should not have stood unless it was truly revolutionary, which this is most definitely not. If, by some chance, they were indeed the first people to patent a closed loop cooler for a cpu then we should thank them for inventing it, but not prevent anyone else from making a closed loop cooler. That is simply a monopoly, and having to pay for a generic description of a cooler is ridiculous when the company themselves merely license the rights to obtain wealth. Yes, yes, they do produce waterblocks themselves, but if someone has a more efficient block or a new pump design they cannot simply sue them out of production because they are also producing a closed loop cooler! They need to innovate, not file generic patents to obstruct competition in the market.

Answer (score 1):

Not my area of expertise, so I cannot assess the patent's novelty. However, I am not sure what you are referring to when you mention the "description" of the patent. It seems the indepent claim is a lot more specific than you state. Also note that the priority date of the patent is in 2003, when liquid CPU cooling systems were not nearly as common as today.

---

A cooling system for a computer system processing unit, comprising:

an integrated element including a heat exchanging interface, a reservoir, and a pump, wherein

the reservoir is configured to receive a cooling liquid from outside the reservoir through an inlet and pass the cooling liquid to the outside through an outlet, the reservoir including an upper chamber and a lower chamber, the upper chamber and the lower chamber being vertically displaced chambers that are separated from each other by at least a horizontal wall and fluidly coupled together by a plurality of substantially circular passages, at least one of the plurality of substantially circular passages being positioned on the horizontal wall, a boundary wall of the lower chamber being formed by the heat exchanging interface;

the heat exchanging interface is adapted to provide separable thermal contact between the processing unit and the cooling liquid such that heat is dissipated from the processing unit to the cooling liquid as the cooling liquid passes through the lower chamber of the reservoir; and

the pump is adapted to direct the cooling liquid through the upper chamber and the lower chamber of the reservoir, the pump including a motor having a rotor, a stator and an impeller having a plurality of curved blades, the impeller being positioned within the reservoir;

a heat radiator spaced apart from the integrated element, the heat radiator being fluidly coupled to the outlet and the inlet of the reservoir, the heat radiator being configured to circulate the cooling liquid therethrough and exhaust heat from the cooling liquid; and
a fan configured to direct air through the heat radiator, the fan being driven by a motor separate from the motor of the pump.